# travis java/maven test integration - run two main class methods

Tags: java, maven, testing, travis-ci

I've got a project [hosted on github](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/laughing-thrift-duck) and I'd like to integrate it with [travis](http://travis-ci.org). I've got two classes that have `main` methods: one is the server and another one is the client. I use NetBeans IDE and I test the software just by running the server file (once) and then running client file (as many times as I want). But this is all manual job. How can I automate this on travis? Shall I use maven for it?

Answer (score -1):

According to the travis documentation (http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/java/) you can use one of the following tools :

- maven
- gradle
- ant

Comment: Yes, I've seen this in the docs as well. But how can I do this, e.g. using maven?